# Different alignments in same environment?

Tags: align

How do I get different alignments in the same align environment? Here some (pseudo)-code to illustrate my idea:

```
\begin{align}
a = &2\\
&+ 3 + 4 \notag\\
&= now I would like the equation sign to be aligned with the first equation sign at line 1
\end{align}
```

Is there any of you LaTeX wizards who can help me?

Answer (score 6):

You have a few choices:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a &= 2+2+2+2+2 \\
  &\quad +3+4
\end{split}
\\
  &= x+y+z
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       & 2+2+2+2+2 \\
       & +3+4
     \end{aligned}
\\
  &= x+y+z
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer the first code :-)

Answer (score 2):

For my tastes I will do your code with this MWE where there is a perfect vertical alignment between `2` and `+` as by screenshot and between two equal signs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= 2\\
&\phantom{{}=}+ 3 + 4 \notag\\
&= \dotsb
\end{align}
\end{document}
```